# Is there a way to set the steam App ID using Fizzy Steamworks in Unity WITHOUT creating steam_appid.txt in the folder with the executable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

The title pretty much sums it up, also this means that a Mac build doesn't work because I don't know where to put `steam_appid.txt`. I'm using 480 as my App ID for now by the way. Is there any way to set the App ID without using `steam_appid.txt`?

I tried to change `SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary()` in the SteamManager script. Here's what it looks like by default:

```
            // If Steam is not running or the game wasn't started through Steam, SteamAPI_RestartAppIfNecessary starts the
            // Steam client and also launches this game again if the User owns it. This can act as a rudimentary form of DRM.
            // Note that this will run which ever version you have installed in steam. Which may not be the precise executable
            // we were currently running.

            // Once you get a Steam AppID assigned by Valve, you need to replace AppId_t.Invalid with it and
            // remove steam_appid.txt from the game depot. eg: "(AppId_t)480" or "new AppId_t(480)".
            // See the Valve documentation for more information: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api#initialization_and_shutdown
            if (SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary(AppId_t.Invalid)) {
                Debug.Log("[Steamworks.NET] Shutting down because RestartAppIfNecessary returned true. Steam will restart the application.");

                Application.Quit();
                return;
            }
```

I changed this: `(SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary(AppId_t.Invalid))` to this: `(SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary((AppId_t)480))` but it crashes right when the splash screen finishes unlesss I put the `steam_appid.txt` in the directory with the executable, then it works as normal, showing a server list. Interestingly it does work in the editor as usual. If I change it back to `AppId_t.Invalid` and run the executable without `steam_appid.txt` it will open just fine, but no servers will appear on the server list.